# setGoalTolerance in Noetic [Moveit]

Tags: python, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to set the cartesian goal tolerance in moveit, using the move_group, in python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380098/setgoaltolerance-in-noetic-%5Bmoveit%5D/) by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2021-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

move_group.set_goal_position_tolerance(0.01)

move_group.set_goal_orientation_tolerance(0.01)

---

Originally posted by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) with karma: 50 on 2021-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-15**:
Is this setting the *path* tolerance, or the *goal* tolerance?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-06-15**:
Those commands are setting the goal tolerance, "path goal tolerance" as mentioned in the original post is difficult to read.